# How did the stigmatisation of nationalism begin?

Tags: nationalism

It is undoubtable that in the modern world the idea of nationalism is frowned upon by many, especially on the left wing, and I'm curious about how this has developed historically.

Can anyone help it proposing ideas as to how nationalism has come to be perceived negatively, is it as a result of Nazism?

Comment: I'd say it's almost certainly a result of Nazism, and their genocidal policies in particular.

Comment: Could you expand on this in a full answer? I don't think it is in particular a result of genocidal policy, as the Aryan race isn't a unifying principle of nationalism, except Blood and Soil Nationalism and even then it's a stretch. I'm thinking more to do with national pride, anti immigration, patriotism and national identity.

Comment: "Aryan race" is just bullshit invented by the nazis which never existed. German ultra-nationalism on the other hand, which was already existing since long eventually leaded to those atrocities SO... now people think if you're a nationalist you actually are analogous to the nazis (whether this is right or not it's opinion based). I don't think I'm knonledgeable on the topic enough to write a full answer.

Comment: The Nazis weren't the first to propose the idea of an Aryan race, they just reappropriated and distorted the idea.

Comment: "has come to be perceived negatively" by who? There have been always proposal for union between countries (for example, on the basis of religion). The nationalism of the French Revolution was fought by the aristocracy of other countries that went to war to defend the French aristocrats. At the start of WWI there were people calling for workers not to enlist to fight other workers from different workers...

Comment: and there are still people who see nationalism positively (see how it is enshrined in the USA, for example -look for "American exceptionalism"-)

Comment: @SJuan76 nationalism has come to be perceived negatively by most, it is now a theocracy reserved only for the far right, when at one time not being nationalist was considered almost criminal and even 100 years ago was a far left idea. There have not always been people calling for union between countries and certainly has never been such a lust for globalisation. Of course there are still some that see it positively but that is beside the premise of the question.

Comment: Do you have any references for all of those "facts" that you assert? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_government#Origins_of_the_idea

Comment: @Charlie do you know the meaning of the word "theocracy"?

Comment: Nationalism is basically the notion that we (nation, not personal) are inherently better than you (nation, not personal).  That's a form of discrimination.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel nice to see you've googled "nationalism" for twenty seconds. No one who ascribes as nationalist would use that definition. Nationalism is the opposite of globalism and believes in borders, strong sense of national pride, patriotism and love for the monarchy and the culture of ones own nation. Spend a bit of time on political SE.

Comment: **"_It is undoubtable that in the modern world the idea of nationalism is frowned upon by many, especially on the left wing_"**:  In the US, Nationalism's really only popular on the Far-Right, typically among traditionalists who feel scared by the rapid rate at which the world's changing.  However, the Right has the strongest opponents of Nationalism, so seeing this as a Right-vs.-Left issue would be a misrepresentation.  ["Red vs. Blue"](http://www.people-press.org/2014/06/26/typology-comparison/free-trade-agreements/), PewResearch, has some quick figures for Nationalist-related views.

Comment: @Bregalad Its popularity has ebbed and flowed, but [internationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalism_(politics)) predates WW2 (or WW1 for that matter).

Comment: I would doubt your premise, belligerent nationalism is probably a little less acceptable to the mainstream in Western Europe but there is still plenty of nationalism to go around and large parts of the world with completely different views on the subject.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**WW1**.

[WW1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_I) started amid a wild enthusiasm in all European nations (cf. [lecture 5 "August Madness"](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/world-war-i-the-great-war.html)).
The wave of nationalism even swept the [SDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Social_Democratic_Party_of_Germany)!

The war was a huge disappointment to everyone involved. This led some intellectuals to question nationalism. However, the war also lead to the first steps of decolonization and creation of nation-states in Eastern Europe.

WW2 was the second phase of the process: even more people questioned nationalism, but even more people embraced it because they now had a hope of having a national homeland.

Comment: Good answer to a question I'd thought was likely unanswerable.

Comment: Yet, after WWII: Independence movements in Western colonies, Israel, Scotland, Quebec, Euskadi, Catalonia, Bangladesh, East Timor, South Sudan, Biafra, dissolution of the Soviet Union and related conflicts, dissolution of Yugoslavia and related conflicts, dissolution of Checoslovakia, Kurds, Brexit; nationalist governments in Russia, India (just to name the more evident ones; I would also add PRC and USA to the list)... and all that just out of the back of my head. And in many cases, nationalism is like the ocean for a fish; we are so deeply in it that we do not notice it.

Comment: I am sorry but seeing how fachism and ultra-nationalism were ultra-popular between world wars (and, contrary to popular belief, not only in Germany !), I fail to see how WW1 would have stopped nationalism.

Comment: @Bregalad: I suggest that you rewrite your comment without subjunctive mood. It makes no sense as it is worded right now.

Comment: Ok, saying the same thing differently: I can see how WW1 made some people started to question nationalism, but they were in minourity, a lot of people were even more nationalist after the war. Only after WW2, massive crimes caused by rasism, this really set the mood for a general "stigmatisation" of nationalism. I think you're inflating the role of WW1 and deflating the role of WW2. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Bregalad: the question was "How did the stigmatisation of nationalism BEGIN?" The answer is "it BEGAN after ww1". it is not over yet - plenty of people, especially those whose right to nationhood is denied, are still full of it.

Comment: @sds Well he asked "How did the STIGMATISATION of nationalism begin?", and the answer is nationalism was QUESTIONNED after WW1 but STIGMATIZED after WW2.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous answer, but as you've mentioned the Left-wing, I'll add some points about that perspective.

It seems that there's an interpretation of Marx's work as to deem nationalism as opposed to the interests of the revolutionary - although he has supported nationalism in some countries where judged it "progressive", instead of a bourgeois invention [see this section for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-wing_nationalism#Marxism_and_nationalism).

For similar reasons, the Trotskyists also defend the creation of an international socialism.

Then, I think wars have always played a role in this movement, as explained in [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/38801/25712).

Answer (score 1):

Nationalism largely originated with Louis XIV.  Political structure prior to this was local government by nobility with the nobles having allegiance to Royalty.  There was little concept of a nation as such.
Louis XIV decoyed the nobility to Versailles and replaced local administration with educated third estate officials under direct control of the king.  Thus the Sun King, where all the rays of power converge.
While very effective for Louis IV and his wars, Louis XVI proved to be superfluous as the third estate converted to French nationalism rather than French royalty.  This is discussed by Jacques Barzun In From Dawn to Decadence, The Monarch's Revolution chapter.

Nationalism clashed with colonialism and areas of influence by foreign powers as when Austria asserted rule over its empire.
Various nationalisms, often religious based, are still in conflict.

Comment: Sources would improve this answer.

Comment: ...being correct would also improve this answer, for that matter.